# Passing date to mysql stored procedure from codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I created the following stored procedure which is working correctly.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SPTeam`(IN date_x date, OUT  emplist3 varchar(200))
BEGIN
select employee.name as emplist3
from employee
where employee.id IN (
  select emp_position.employee_id
  from emp_position
  where emp_position.employee_id NOT IN (
     select emp_event.employee_id
     from emp_event
     where emp_event.date = date_x
  )
  AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman"
 );
END
```

I'm calling this stored procedure by the following code in codeigniter model.

```
  $SQL = "call SPTeam("
    . $date.","
    . " @emplist3" //output
    .");";

$this->db->trans_start();
    $query = $this->db->query($SQL); 
    $this->db->trans_complete();
$result = array();
foreach($query->result() as $rows){
    $result[]=$rows;
}
return $query->result();
}
```

In my controller I pass the $date to the above model function as follows.

```
    $date = '06/12/2016';
    $data= $this->employee_model->sp_call($date) ;
```

But it gives a wrong result.
I tried the following date format too.

```
    $date = '2016-12-14';
    $data= $this->employee_model->sp_call($date) ;
```

It gives the following error.

```
Error Number: 1292

Incorrect date value: '1990' for column 'date_x' at row 1

call SPTeam(2016-12-14, @emplist3);
```

Someone Please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few different things.  First, make sure the string value being passed into the SP is of YYYY-MM-DD format, since this is a Date column in MySQL.

Also, the SP might require the date string being passed in to have single quotes around it in order to process correctly.

Try something like this:

```
$date = "'2016-12-14'";
```

Or this (notice the addition of the single quotes):

```
 $SQL = "call SPTeam('"
    . $date."',"
    . " @emplist3" 
    .");";
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to adjust your SP to use the **[STR_TO_DATE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)** in MySQL.  Since you are technically passing in a string, you might need to make sure it is formatted accordingly.

Hope this helps.